# Drupal 7 Commerce Stock - Setup stock rules on purchase success for all line items?

Tags: 7, rules, commerce

Currently im trying to setup the stock rules for drupal 7 commerce, but I'm not sure how to go about setting up the rules to deduct stock on purchase success. I have the following: http://prntscr.com/24d0b5

As for the following action: Decrease the product stock level, given a line item

I have this: http://prntscr.com/24d0u8

Currently it only applies to line-item:0 , But how do I make it apply to all line items? Can someone take a snapshot of how their configuration is for this stock rules setup?

thanks

Comment: A loop in rules. I will see my setting & will post you answer soon.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, make sure there is a Line items loop(Data Selector -> commerce-order:commerce-line-items). Then While adding the action, please make sure it is added to the already added Line item Loop(you will find under the 'operations' tab) and NOT as a new 'Add action' at the bottom.